# a value is required for '--target <targets>...' but none was supplied when install rust

Tags: jenkins, rust, rustup

The command is `curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y --profile=default -t --target x86_64-apple-darwin --no-modify-path`

This command worked fine before, but for some reason now it's giving me an error. I think sh.rustup.rs is updated so it can not read my params --target x86_64-apple-darwin

Is there other way to install rustc on the packaging Server?

Answer (score 3):

You have redundant options: `-t` and `--target` do the same thing. Remove either to have it work, ie.

```bash
$ curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y --profile=default --target x86_64-apple-darwin --no-modify-path
```